# Angularjs : Access nested json array values using ng-repeat with groupBy

Tags: angularjs, json, grouping, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've nested json array in which i need to group with some values. I'm not able to fetch nested tag for grouping.

```
$scope.sampleTest = [{"id": "1", "cash": {"amount":"4000"}},
                     {"id": "2", "cash": {"amount":"2000"}}]
```

If i'm grouping 'id' its working and if i'm grouping 'cash.amount' its not working

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
<div ng-repeat="record in sampleTest | filter: {cash:{amount:'2000'}}:true ">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
   $scope.sampleTest = [{"id": "1", "cash": {"amount":"4000"}},
                     {"id": "2", "cash": {"amount":"2000"}},
                        {"id": "3", "cash": {"amount":"2000"}}];
 
   
  
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="dobController">
 <div ng-repeat="record in sampleTest | filter: {cash:{amount:'2000'}}:true ">
     <ul>
       <li >{{ record}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
 
</body>

</html>
```